# Admin approval notification based on role choose by user on registration form?

Tags: users

I need to set admin approval for a particular role. I am using auto assign module to provide user to choose role on registration form.

authenticated users: Do not need admin approval

```
$form_state['values']['status'] = 1;

$form["account"]["status"]["#default_value"] = FALSE;
```

Try to use above line on validate function but not getting any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a module for this, which addresses my question. It can be found at [Select registration roles](https://www.drupal.org/project/select_registration_roles). Some more details about it (from its project page):

> The Select Registration Roles module adds a role field on the user registration form. Admin can configure roles to be displayed on the
>   registration form as, and can set roles which require admin approval.

Here is a screenprint of it also:

[image]

Comment: nice! Please check my edit of your answer (now that it is a full project). If you don't like the edit, just perform a rollback, ok?

Comment: Thank you @Pierre.Vriens. Yes you are right. Now it is a full project. Thank you edit the answer.